# Failed to determine console output code page: The system could not find the environment option that was entered.. Falling back to UTF-8

Tags: node.js, webstorm

В командной строке "npm run start" запускает сборку. Если дать аналогичную команду в терминале webstorm, то система выдаёт ошибку: "Failed to determine console output code page: The system could not find the environment option that was entered.. Falling back to UTF-8".
Кодировка проекта установлена UTF-8.Такая ошибка только на части проектов, с идентичными настройками. На борту windows 10 (все обновления установлены), webstorm 2021.3 лицензия, node.js 16.4 (последняя стабильная), uac переведён в позицию минимум. Весь софт прописан в системный и пользовательский path'ы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

выключение `terminal.use.conpty.on.windows` опции в registry (**Help | Find Action...**, введите `Registry`) должно помочь.